Weighing out Cinestill dry C-41 materials
I develop C-41 just infrequently enough to waste chemistry due to lack of shelf life, even with tetanol and a frig. (That is, the concentrates expiring.) An alternative: buy a precise scale, buy CineStill dry kits, and weigh out enough to make 500ml at a throw.
Can I assume that the dry chems are homogeneous enough?

I have never had, nor heard of any issues with inconsistency of mix. That said, it has been quite a while since I have developed film.
You could also buy the individual chemical components separately from somewhere like B&H to ensure exact ratios.

I have never tried, but relatively common sense would indicate that you should not do so.
Ilford warns against such practice in the instructions for all their powdered developers: 'Always make up the developer stock solution to the volume stated on the pack, do not attempt to prepare smaller solution quantities by using fractional parts of each powder.' I did not find anything about this mentioned in the Cinestill instructions, but they are relatively sparse and not as verbose as the Ilford instructions.
The reason is simply that mixed powdered chemicals are in general not homogeneous. Due to particle segregation, smaller grains and more dense substances will sink to the bottom and larger grains and less dense substances will float on the top. You can not expect the ratios of each component to stay constant if you split up a powder mix into several portions.
